# Code::Blocks doesn't work properly

Tags: codeblocks

[the black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Arziz.png)

So, long story short, code blocks got corrupted or something like that last week, i didn't find the solution online or here but, i managed to see that somehow the code blocks didn't work while it wasn't working while in local desk (C) - because i tried to install it on an other local desk and it worked fine today - but when i came to use code blocks tonight and did everything i needed to do and built it and now i am going to run the code, the black screen shows but doesn't take INPUT OR GIVES OUTPUT, NOTHING. just like it froze.
didn't find a solution for that problem and i really hope i find it here.

Comment: Please, try to separate your sentences by punctuation. I **really** tried to understand what you are talking about, and the only thing I understood was that CodeBlocks doesn't seem to work. I know the language barrier is hard, but if you try and put some effort into editing your question, I am sure somebody will be able to help. I am out, since I do not use Windows.

Comment: it's my first time here, and english is not my first language so, yeah.

Comment: This site is more about helping people who have problems with code they have written than with trying to troubleshoot general software failures.  While codeblocks is a programming tool, what you are asking here is for troubleshooting the program, not troubleshooting it's effects on your written code, and that makes the question too broad to be answered here.

Comment: @Claies dude, the problem here is not with the code, if i compile the code online it's no probs , the problem here is that the compiler is corrupted.

Comment: Which is **exactly** why this is off topic here.

Comment: well this is bad... cuz i can't find the solution for my problem anywhere.